# Region of Convergence for the complex series $\sum {((z-1)/(z+2))^k} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve this problem from the textbook "A First Course in Complex Analysis with Applications" in section 6.1.

The question asks to sketch the region of convergence of the following series:

$\sum {((z-1)/(z+2))^k} $

So, I tried using the ratio test, and I found that $ {|((z-1)/(z+2))| < 1} $. This leads to a lot of algebraic equations and boils down to

$ \sqrt{\frac{x^{4}+y^{4}+2x^{3}-3x^{2}+5y^{2}+x^{2}y^{2}-4x+y^{2}x^{2}+2xy^{2}+4}{\left(\left(x+2\right)^{2}+y^{2}\right)^{2}}}<1  $

I tried simplifying it, but I got this.

$-6x^{3}-27x^{2}-36x-6y^{2}x-3y^{2}-12<1$

So, my questions are:

- Is there an easier way to figure out the region of convergence?
- Is there an easy way to sketch the first inequality?
- More importantly, Why when I sketch the first inequality using a graphic calculator, it looks like its the same as $ {x>-1/2} $? and are they same?

This is a link to the desmos graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zimzjveiet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test is a sufficient but not necessary condition of convergence.

For a geometric series with ratio $q$, the necessary and sufficient condition is $|q|<1$.

Your complicated numerator is probably wrong.

$$\left|\frac{z-1}{z+2}\right|<1\Leftrightarrow(x-1)^2+y^2<(x+2)^2+y^2\Leftrightarrow x>-\frac12.$$

Comment: I am so dumb,  I don't know why it didn't occur to me I can just multiply by |z+2|. I have to recheck my steps in order to make sure the numerator is correct.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your numerator was not correct (test with $x=0,y=1$).